# Both iPhone cameras on the same view?

Tags: ios, swift

I've had a look around online, and had a play around with it myself but have been unable to find literally anything on this topic, I assume it's never really been played around with before.

```
let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices().filter{ $0.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) && $0.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back }
    if let captureDevice = devices.first as? AVCaptureDevice  {


        do {
            try sessionCap.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
        } catch {

        }

        sessionCap.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
        sessionCap.startRunning()

        stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        if sessionCap.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            sessionCap.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        }

        if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: sessionCap) {

            previewLayer.bounds = view.bounds
            previewLayer.position = CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY)
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

            let cameraPreview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height))

            cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            cameraPreview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(ViewController.saveToCamera(_:))))

            view.addSubview(cameraPreview)
        }
    }
```

So this is the code I have at the moment, basically what it does it it shows the iPhone back facing camera on the ViewController, and I have other code that takes allows the user to take the picture - great. However, I was wondering how possible it would be to add both cameras on to the same view?

[Screen View Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MNUJ.png)

The black area would be the front facing camera ("selfie camera"), and the cyan area would be the back facing camera. I'm going to continue looking while this is posted here, but I feel like it's a lost cause.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me to be impossible.

You cannot use both cameras at the same time, as they are not allowed simultaneously. So as soon as one `AVCaptureSession` begins, the other `AVCaptureSession` will stop because it requires device hardware.